# Dotted vertical line in math array + siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, arrays

This works until I uncomment siunitx. I presume this is a bug? Should I file anywhere?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Uncommenting this line breaks this document. It will trigger a compilation error on the dotted line indicator.
%\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{c : c : c}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `siunitx` before `arydshln`. And no need to load both `mathtools` and amsmath`. `mathtools` loads `amsmath` too.

Comment: That worked. How did you know? Is there a simple explanation? That seems very sloppy/hacky to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `siunitx` package loads `array`, part of the standard `tools` bundle for LaTeX (this is needed to allow the `S` and `s` column types to work). However, both `array` and `arydshln` make changes to the standard `tabular` mechanism and I suspect do no tests for other redefinitions. Thus you need to load `array` *before* `arydshln`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{c : c : c : S}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 12.3\\
        4 & 5 & 6 & 4.56\\
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

(`S` column added to show that things still work properly.)