# Dashed lines and point-aligned numbers in a column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, rules, arydshln

How can I have these two features at the same time in a table: dashed lines, and numbers aligned on their decimal points?

MWE (except it doesn't work):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for \hdashline
\usepackage{siunitx} % for column type S
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.1]}
14\\
\hdashline
9.5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This gives the error:

```
7
Undefined control sequence.
\adl@hline ...mpcnta \xdef \adl@rowsL {\adl@rowsL 
                                                  (#1/\number \@tempcnta );}...

l.7 \hdashline
```

Perhaps `arydshln` was the wrong package to use for the dashed line? `\hdashrule` in package `dashrule`, as far as I can tell, can't produce a rule confined to a table.

Perhaps `siunitx` was the wrong package to use for point-aligning? I tried package `dcolumn` and column type `D{.}{.}{1}` but that failed, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the `siunitx` package before `arydshln` the MWE works. See also the related question: [Dotted vertical line in math array + siunitx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195411/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for column type S
\usepackage{arydshln} % for \hdashline
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.1]}
14\\
\hdashline
9.5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can also load the `array` package before `arydshln`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for \hdashline
\usepackage{siunitx} % for column type S
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.1]}
14\\
\hdashline
9.5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your earlier suggestion of `\usepackage{array}` before `\usepackage{arydshln}` might also be worth putting onto the record. A rule "If you use package Y, use package X first" seems easy to work with, provided X doesn't introduce its own conditions. But a rule "If you use packages Y and Z, use Y before Z" might contribute to later grief if many such dependencies arise and interact.